# Autosave to Firestore lagging

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am autosaving to Firestore every time the user modifies anything in the text field. My code is:

```
self.collection.document(noteID!).updateData(["note.title": noteTitle.text, "note.lastUpdatedTimestamp": time])
```

It has started lagging very heavily all of a sudden. Is there a way to batch writes within a document to avoid this heavy lagging?

Comment: Why wouldn't you update this when the user is done typing altogether instead of on each character change?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing terribly inefficient about that line of code that could be improved.  Splitting this up into an update per field would not help.  It's more likely the case that your network connection is slower than normal, or that somehow one of the fields is much longer than usual, which increases the time it takes to update.